# R CMD check Warning: Non-standard license specification

Tags: r, package, licensing, cran

When I run `R CMD check` I get a warning:

```
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
Non-standard license specification:
  use_mit_license()
Standardizable: FALSE
```

I can't figure out how my license should be formatted in my DESCRIPTION file. Right now it is formatted like this (which I thought was correct):

```
License: use_mit_license()
```

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: instead of formatting it in the description file what if you run that command in the console under your r package

Comment: Do you mind sharing an example of what that might look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first delete the license line out out of your description file, save it then close it. in the R console, while your R project is open (R package in this case). run this line in the console `use_mit_license()`. This will add information to the rbuildignore file, add a .md file for the license and should add the license information to the description file (check this after you run the code).

Here is some more information on the topic: https://r-pkgs.org/license.html

Comment: Command from usethis library (e.g. usethis::use_gpl_license())